# Missed registration deadline that was not announced for second exam of a course, how should I proceed?

Tags: exams, germany, covid-19

I am an undergraduate student in Germany.

Due to scheduling problems I couldn't attend an exam last semester. Subsequently, because of COVID-19, the date for the second exam was unknown. To register for an exam you need to access the list where all university courses are listed, and then just click on the exam and press on a participate button. I did not want to register for the second exam before the date was announced, because I did not want to have this show up in my grades if I did not attend.

The professor only sent the e-mail of the date of the exam to those registered for the second exam, excluding the students otherwise registered for the course or the first exam. Also, no information on the second exam is available on the course page. Yesterday, I got an e-mail from the professor about hygiene and covid measures in the exam which apparently is this Friday. Also, the deadline for entering was 2 weeks ago. In all the other courses I participated in, all attendants of the course got information for the second exam.

After explaining the situation to the professor I got the answer that attending now is not possible.

This is an incredibly bad situation for me. My whole plan on finishing my degree in time depends on passing this exam. Otherwise I won't be able to attend a lot of courses that have this course as a prerequisite. Effectively, I will need a year longer to finish my bachelors.

How shall I proceed? Do I have any rights for a third exam in this situation?

Comment: Did you check (from time to time) if there was a registration deadline mentioned in the university-wide course list where you register?

Comment: I did not. I assumed this information would be sent to me.

Comment: As a lecturer at a German university, the informal appraoch is via the lecturer. If s/he does not register you for your exam, try a formal approach via 'Prüfungsausschuss' or the 'Prüfungsamt'. I can only speak for a few institution, but COVID19 has opened processes here and there for exceptions, especially concerning third tries on exams.
PS: Never ever expect that information is just sent to you. Studying means to be responsible for yourself. This includes informing on dates and deadlines. As unfair as this mitght sound.

Comment: @HATEthePLOT I agree! but due to the current crisis, everything is subject to change. As a lecturer at a German university, I used to announce everything on our webpage expecting the students to check but if the announced information is subject to change, we need to convey it to the students ensuring that they have the last updated one. Unfortunately, the universities want to strictly stick to the rules giving the lecturers the responsibility to manage the exams in the way they find convenient.

Comment: Often a professor will ask students to register for an exam to establish how many so that some relevant logistics can be worked out - room size, number of papers etc. By not registering that means the professor has not prepared material so cannot add you to the list late. Perhaps you should prepare for the next cycle.

Comment: @HATEthePLOT Asking the lecturer, the Prüfungsamt and the Prüfungsausschuss (in that order) to register you sounds like a good answer to me. Why don't you turn it into one instead of answering in the comments.

Comment: I did that already. I can participate in the exam now, which is great. This is quite embarrassing but apparently I signed up for the test months ago. I thought I did not, because in my correspondence with the professor he wrote that he sent the e-mail to all participants. I do not understand the second sentence.

Answer (score 2):

As proposed by @Sumyrda - remember Monica, I post my comment as a possible solution.

As a lecturer at a German university, I suggest the following: the informal appraoch is via the lecturer. If s/he does not register you for your exam, try a formal approach via 'Prüfungsausschuss' or the 'Prüfungsamt'. I can only speak for a few institution I worked for (from rather small to bigger universities): the processes are quite different and thus are your option to register for tests, exams or written essays, etc. Since COVID19, universities have opened processes here and there for exceptions, especially concerning third tries on exams and registration processes. However, these are regulated on a institutional, often even on a chair-basis.